# two norms are not equivalent then at least one of them is discontinuous on the unit sphere in the other norm

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Prove that if two norms on the same vector space are not equivalent then at least one of them is discontinuous on the unit sphere in the other norm. Can each norm be discontinuous when restricted to the unit sphere of the other?

We know that if $\Vert\cdot\Vert$ and $\Vert\cdot\Vert'$ are not equivalent, then either for every $C>0$ there exists $x$ with $\Vert x\Vert>C\Vert x\Vert'$ or for every $C>0$ there exists $x$ with $\Vert x\Vert'>C\Vert x\Vert$.

Need some hints to proceed with the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose there exists no $C$ so that $\|\cdot\|_2≤C\,\|\cdot\|_1$. Then you can find a sequence of $\|\cdot\|_1$-unit vectors $x_n$ so that $\|x_n\|_2≥2^n$. Now $\frac{x_1+1/n x_n}{\|x_1 + 1/n x_n\|_1}$ is a sequence of $\|\cdot\|_1$-unit vectors converging to $x_1$ in $\|\cdot\|_1$. However the two norm of these guys is
$$\left\|\frac{x_1+1/nx_n}{\|x_1+1/nx_n\|_1}\right\|_2≥\frac{\left|1/n\|x_n\|_2- \|x_1\|_2\right|}{\|x_1+1/n x_n\|_1}≥\frac{\left|2^n/n- \|x_1\|_2\right|}{\|x_1+1/n x_n\|_1}$$
which does not converge $\|x_1\|_2$, so $\|\cdot\|_2$ is discontinous on the unit sphere of $\|\cdot\|_1$.

If you have $\|\cdot\|_1≤ C\|\cdot\|_2$ however, then any $\|\cdot\|_2$ Cauchy Sequence is Cauchy on $\|\cdot\|_1$, and $\|\cdot\|_1$ is continuous on the entire vector space thus also on the unit sphere.

Comment: The unit *sphere* is not the same thing as the unit *ball*.

Comment: @PhoemueX oh, right. I rewrote it then.